# Browsing Connections via API

Tags: linkedin-api

My team has set up an app in LinkedIn and we would like to be able to browse our connections. I'm not sure which API I should request access to, as I am unsure which API will allow us to browse our connections.

Any documentation around connection endpoints would be very helpful.

I am hoping to leverage the python api library (linkedin-api-client).